# Handle DateTime Timezone with c# / json / android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, json

I have a SQL Server database which contains date like 2012-01-10 00:00:00.000

When I retrieve taht date and put it in JSON, it will be transformed like "/Date(1326150000000+0100)/"

On my android terminal device, I keep only the milliseconds informations and transform it into a Date, the result is Mon Jan 09 23:00:00 UTC+00:00 2012.

The problem is that the date is really important and all the users are in the same time zone.

Do you know how to handle this case ? I thinked about the solution to find the timezone and add this timespan to the date but i didn't find how to find the +1 information ? Another solution would be to handle the timezone with android ..

Can someone help me ?

regards

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: oups my web service is in c# and use the sql server data

Comment: What's wrong with printing the date in ISO-8601 timestamps instead of that odd "/Date(....+0100)/" kludge? In that case you could use the SimpleDateFormat (or similar) to parse your date & time and it would adjust for whatever time zone is included in the output of your web service.

Comment: well i agree with you but wcf web service export date with that format and I have to deal with :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldnt you create a string property on wcf to replicate the date, but with "normal" formatting? In this case instead of sending a date, you could send the date.tostring("yyyy-mm-dd")